# How do I get it to conosle.log the "Read It" before the "Ex It"?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

```
app.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    await fs.readFile('./views/website/index.html', 'utf8', (err, d) => {
        data = d
        console.log("Read It")
            // console.log(data)
    });

    console.log("Ex It")
    res.render('website/index', { 'data': data });
});
```

I tried to use the async function and await, but when I run it, it is console logging the "Ex It" before the "Read It". How do it get it to output the "Read It" before the "Ex It"?

Comment: fs.readFile does not return a Promise. So using await on it is pointless

Comment: @JaromandaX It depends on the import statement.

Comment: Is there a way to do it correctly? I haven't really learned how to use the async functions.

Comment: @jabaa. True. But the callback is a dead giveaway

Comment: @CalebGross. Import the promise version of fs

Comment: Replace `import fs from 'fs';` with `import fs from 'fs/promises';` and rewrite the callback.

Comment: And dont use the callback (err, d) when using Promise version. Read the documentation for more info

Comment: And after change you should not fix await and then. `var data = await fs.readFile('...');`

Comment: So like this? ```var data = await fs.readFile('./views/website/index.html', 'utf8', (err, d) => { console.log("Read It") });```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the [promises version](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/docs/api/fs.html#fs_fspromises_readfile_path_options) as suggested by the comments ["`require('fs').promises`"](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/docs/api/fs.html#fs_fs_promises_api)

```
app.get('/', async (req, res) => {
  data = await fs.promises.readFile('./views/website/index.html', 'utf8');
  console.log("Read It")
  console.log("Ex It")
  res.render('website/index', { 'data': data });
});
```

or just put everything in the callback

```
app.get('/', async (req, res) => {
  fs.readFile('./views/website/index.html', 'utf8', (err, d) => {
      data = d
      console.log("Read It")
      console.log("Ex It")
      res.render('website/index', { 'data': data });
  });
});
```

or you could wrap the callback in a [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

```
app.get('/', async (req, res) => {
  await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fs.readFile('./views/website/index.html', 'utf8', (err, d) => {
      data = d
      console.log("Read It")
      resolve();
    });
  });

  console.log("Ex It")
  res.render('website/index', { 'data': data });
});
```

or use the synchronous version (actually don't do this)

```
app.get('/', async (req, res) => {
  data = fs.readFileSync('./views/website/index.html', 'utf8');
  console.log("Read It")
  console.log("Ex It")
  res.render('website/index', { 'data': data });
});
```